# How to do XA transaction which includes JDBC and JMS transactions?

Tags: java, jdbc, jms, xa

I need to do XA transaction in JavaSE with JDBC and JMS Queues.

I have weblogic server to lookup for resources.

Could you help me with some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide code, but you must keep these things in mind when doing two-phase commit with JDBC and JMS resources in WebLogic...

**JMS General Settings**

- Configure the JMSconnection factory to use: weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/JMSjmsconnectionjmsconnectionfactoryconfigtransactionparamstitle.html

**JDBC General Settings**

- Configure JDBC connection pool to use XA-compliant JDBC driver.

From the code perspective, either control the transaction from MDB or Spring bean with transaction annotations; the J2EE containers will handle the global commit/rollback.